# URL to edit image with media uploader thickbox

Tags: image, wordpress, media, thickbox

I'm using WordPress 3.5 and trying to figure out how can I edit an image by clicking on it to get to the media uploader thickbox.

**What I found out so far**

The URL below work fine but I need to EDIT a special image, not add one. I have an attachment ID.

```
/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=1&type=image&TB_iframe=1&width=640&height=553
```

To make the thickbox work I need to add the classes `info thickbox`.

**Question**

I found many articles on how to upload images but not how to edit them. Maybe I can just add some get variale to get it to work?

Comment: Why are you using the old thickbox-iframe way of doing it instead of the new uploader in 3.5+?

Comment: This was what I found on the web. If you have a better solution, please tell me more about it.

Comment: That is for 3.4 and below. Why not use this? http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/

Comment: The (relatively) new media interface still holds many mysteries :) I think this question should be migrated to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: It could, though there may be more backbone.js experts on SO.